# Unable to run the getting started docker

Tags: windows, docker

I have just reinstalled Docker Desktop 4.8.2 on Windows 10.

When I run `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started` in the terminal I get the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
```

and then:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I'm working behind a proxy and the proxy settings in Docker Desktop are correct.

Comment: The first error is normal. It means it couldn't find the image in the local repository (because it was never downloaded). It will then try to search the hub instead. It looks like it's unable to reach the hub for some unrelated reason.

Comment: Searching for this issue I've seen that setting the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 might solve the problem but I don't know what it does, and I don't know if I'm allowed to do that with my company's computer...

Comment: That's Google's DNS server. I don't think there's anything inherently unsafe about that, except your current DNS might block requests to unwanted domains.

Comment: I didn't solve the problem but I get a new error:  Failed to lookup host: registry-1.docker.io.